# Redis Conf symlinks problems

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

Is there any way that I can set up a symlink to /etc/redis.conf to a different location than /etc/redis/redis.conf and work? Let's say I have the file in my local directory, and instead of copying the file to /etc/redis/, I want to create the symlink to /etc/redis/redis.conf.
I have been trying and still fail.
Any help would be appreciated.